# R network package - is there a faster way to add edges?

Tags: r

I have an adjacency matrix (m) of 7000 nodes. Creating a network from this using

```
n <- 7000
m <- matrix(rbinom(3*n, 1, 0.2), n,n)
diag(m) <- 0
g <- network(m, directed = F)
```

is very slow. Is there a more efficient way of creating large random networks in R? Alternative methods such as using iGraph would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With igraph, you can do:

```
library('igraph')
g <- graph.adjacency(m, mode='undirected')
```

The edges can then be retrieved using `E(g)` and vertices using `V(g)`.

Check out the [igraph docs](http://igraph.org/r/#rdoc1) for more information.

Comment: Thanks I never realised how good igraph was; had always been happy using network